# Заполнение таблицы формулами после обновления запроса

Tags: excel, vba

Какой использовать макрос для автозаполнения формы в таблице с формулами?

Есть связанный запрос на обновление данных из файла, есть таблица, в которой происходит рефреш данных, в таблице есть расчетные столбцы, которые приходится вручную протягивать для заполнения.

Есть ли какой нибудь код для подобной операции в VBA?

Comment: Запускаешь макрорекордер, протягиваешь вручную - вот тебе и код.

Comment: >> *Есть связанный запрос... есть таблица* - нет ничего...

Comment: VBA самоучка, многого еще незнаю подскажите, что же указать чтобы макрос работал с таблицей а не с определенным диапазоном: 
    Range("M1527:Z1527").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("M1527:Z1534"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("M1527:Z1534").Select
    Application.Goto Reference:="Макрос1"
End Sub

Comment: Я же не зря писал, что нет ничего... Покажите пример таблиц в файле, где что нужно заполнить.

Comment: Коммерческая тайна не позволит выложить сам файл, но вид такой - есть столбцы : Дата,Сумма,Назначение платежа,Контрагент, которые через запрос с файла выгружаются с 1с, а также расчетные формулы по взаимодействию с этими столбцами. При открытии файл рефрешает запрос и дополняет строки, но таблица не заполняет новые строки таблицы формулами

Comment: Разницу между "пример" и "рабочий файл" понимаете? Меняйте патроны на огурцы, откаты на подарки, звания на клички ) Сами сможете применить подсказку, если не будет примера, куда вставлять формулы?

Answer (score 0):

Примера нет, танцуем свободный танец.

Данные обновляются на листе `Sheet1`. В столбце С формула. Строки ниже вставляемых данных пустые (пользовательский диапазон ограничен последней строкой с новыми даннми).

Вешаем макрос на какую-нибудь кнопулю. Жмем и...

Определяем номер последней строки с формулой (`lRwOld`), находим последнюю строку с данными (`lRwNew`) - после обновления данных она будет ниже строки с формулой. Все. Заполняем пустой диапазон столбца С.

```
Sub CopyFormula()
    Dim lRwOld As Long, lRwNew As Long

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        lRwOld = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).row
        lRwNew = .UsedRange.Rows.Count + .UsedRange.row - 1
        .Range(.Cells(lRwOld, 3), .Cells(lRwNew, 3)).FillDown
    End With
End Sub
```

Если столбцов с формулами больше (например, C:E):

```
.Range(.Cells(lRwOld, 3), .Cells(lRwNew, 5)).FillDown
' или'
.Cells(lRwOld, 3).Resize(lRwNew - lRwOld + 1, 3).FillDown
```

Строку с `FillDown` можно заменить на вставку формул (`.Formula`, `.FormulaLocal`, `.FormulaR1C1`...)

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло